# Quick Look video scrubbing on macOS High Sierra

Tags: macos, high-sierra, quicklook

Previously, when previewing a video in Quick Look, scrolling right and left on the trackpad would scrub forward and backward, but after upgrading to macOS High Sierra, this seems no longer to be the case.

Is there any way to re-enable this setting? Or, if not, are there any alternative ways to scrub? (Dragging the line on the progress bar is not nuanced enough, especially for longer videos.)

Comment: I'm on High Sierra beta and I can scrub using the trackpad, so either it's a bug with a specific version of High Sierra and to be fixed in a future update or something else is preventing it working, but it doesn't look like the feature's been removed on purpose.

Comment: @grgarside Well, that's encouraging, at least.

Comment: It's been weeks now, and I have confirmed this behavior on multiple machines. Also, I found this Apple support thread, so it's definitely not just me. https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8089735?start=15&tstart=0

Comment: The hours and RSI this feature would have saved me had I known about it years ago…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of macOS 10.13.2 (17C88) it is working correctly once again.